# Get HTML response from AccuWeather using Python Requests

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have been trying for quite a while now to get the html response from the following URL using requests:

https://www.accuweather.com/en/pk/islamabad/258278/december-weather/258278

My goal is to use regex or selenium to get the monthly temperature data from the html received. If succeeded, I can then use the same method to get the monthly record of any city given the right location code and then create a temperature dataset for a project I am working on.

I have tried various headers as best I could find from the Chrome Inspect tool but I am a true beginner so I have no clue where I am falling short since I constantly being denied access. Any help will be appreciated!

P.S - I have also noticed that the final location code is the main key in accessing the URL. For example you will reach the same page as above with the following URL:

https://www.accuweather.com/x/x/x/x/december-weather/258278

Comment: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/ Beautiful Soup should do what you're looking for. You input whatever URL you want as a string, and use for example soup.findall("p") to find everything with a p tag. Everything is super easy to work with, and the HTML parser returns everything as a string.

Comment: They also have some free APIs https://developer.accuweather.com/

Comment: I don't think I can use Beautiful Soup to get an HTML response from the web. For that I need requests and I am getting Access Denied